# cakephp 2 - load helper depending on layout

Tags: cakephp, layout, helper, cakephp-2.2

i would like to load helpers depending on layouts.
i want something like this,  but id doesnt't work:

```
function beforeRender(){
  if (array_key_exists($this->request->action, $this->custom_layouts)){
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session', 'Menu1');                
    $this->layout = $this->custom_layouts[$this->action];

  }else{
    public $helpers = array(
      'Session',
      'Html' => array('className' => 'TwitterBootstrap.BootstrapHtml'),
      'Form' => array('className' => 'TwitterBootstrap.BootstrapForm'),
      'Paginator' => array('className' => 'TwitterBootstrap.BootstrapPaginator'),
      'Menu1'
    );
    $this->layout = 'default';
  }
}
```

thanks for any help
regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant juse declare `public $helpers` inside methods.

You need to call it as PHP wants it to be called:

```
$this->helpers[] = 'Menu1';
$this->helpers['Html'] = array('className' => 'TwitterBootstrap.BootstrapHtml');
...
```

Comment: Please test if dynamically using different helpers with the same Alias (e.g. sometimes $this->Html is mapped to 'BootstrapHtmlHelper' and sometimes to 'HtmlHelper') works as expected. Assigning the same alias to different classes may cause problems with the Cake cache and may lead to unexpected results (e.g. randomly attaching the 'wrong' type of object). At least, this is the case with 'Models', but the same *may* apply to other classes as well

Comment: thank you very much mark, works perfect. Up to now it works as expected

Comment: @martin good to hear, just be sure to test it with debug set to 0 as well, because only then caching is fully enabled.

Comment: @thaJeztah i tried now with debug set to 0 and it seems to work. I use for the frontend twitter bootstrap plugin with a adapted layout and for the admin backend then cakephp standard default layout without twitter bootstrap. What i do now: In AppController i don't load the public helpers html and form because i don't use own helpers, so it is not necesary because they load by themselve. In case of detection of admin views, o load html, form and paginator helpers as indicated by mark.